# How to handle scenario where numpy.where condition is unsatisfied?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am converting this array:

`x = np.array([[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]])`

to: `[2, 0, 1, 0, 0]`.

Basically, I want to return the index of the first `1` in each sub-array. However, my problem is that I don't know how to handle the scenario where there is no `1`. I want it to return `0` if `1` is not found (like in my example).

The code below works fine but throws `IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0` for the scenario I mentioned:

`np.array([np.where(r == 1)[0][0] for r in x])`

What is an easy way to handle this? It does not need to be restricted to numpy.where.

I am using Python 3 by the way.

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple modification to your code would be to add a condition to the list comprehension:

```
np.array([np.where(r == 1)[0][0] if 1 in r else 0 for r in x])
# 23.1 µs ± 43.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

A more concise and substantially faster way of obtaining the same result is:

```
np.argmax(x == 1, axis=1)
# 4.04 µs ± 45.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

or, equivalently:

```
np.argmin(x != 1, axis=1)
# 4.03 µs ± 13.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `mask` of `1s` and then `argmax` along each row to get the first matching index alongwith `any` to check for valid rows (rows with at least one `1`) -

```
mask = x==1
idx = np.where(mask.any(1), mask.argmax(1),0)
```

Now, `argmax` on all `False` would return `0`. So, that plays right into the hands of the stated problem. As such, we can simply use `mask.argmax(1)` result. But in a general case, where the invalid specifier, let's call it `invalid_val` is not `0`, we can specify there inside `np.where`, like so -

```
idx = np.where(mask.any(1), mask.argmax(1),invalid_val)
```

Another method would be to get the first matching index on the mask and then index into the mask to see if any of the indexed values is `False` and set those as `0s` -

```
idx = mask.argmax(1)
idx[~mask[np.arange(len(idx)), idx]] = 0 # or invalid_val
```